# Collapsable navbar disappears after opening

Tags: bootstrap-4

When I click the navbar toggler button, it opens and after that the sliding animation  disappears. How can I fix this?
Thanks

I've tried pasting the responsive navbar code from the bootstrap website and still the same issue. I've also tried moving the booststrap script to the bottom of the page just before the closing the body tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
  integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Nagigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container w-50 ml-0">
      <a class="navbar-brand ml-5" href="#"><img src="images/music logo.png" class="w-25" alt="piano store logo"> Premium Pianos</a>
    </div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hello">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="hello">
      <ul class="navbar-nav w-50 justify-content-around">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">How it works</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Pricing</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this? [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>    
    </ul>
  </div>  
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just copied the head section from w3 schools example and that seemed to work. This is confusing because I researched similar issues and they all said to put the jQuery script before the bootstrap script which I did. However the w3 example did not but it works?